# A circuit which charges and uses a lithium ion battery

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, charging, power-management

I am designing a circuit which will utilise a lithium ion battery. The circuit would ideally be plugged into a power source the majority of the time, butI would also like it to be portable. I have been doing some research into battery charging and management ICs and circuits. They all seem to be aimed towards charging removable batteries.

How would I go about wiring in a lithium ion battery so that it can be charged and used within the same circuit?

Comment: Could you choose one or two datasheets that you feel are representative and _edit your question_ by including links to them?  I haven't personally designed such a chip into a circuit, but from skimming datasheets I've been left with the impression that they address exactly your use case.  If not, then one might with a bit of help from a microprocessor.

Comment: I believe Texas instruments makes several battery charging ICs that can charge lithium batteries (whether they are permanently wired in or removable).  https://www.ti.com/power-management/battery-management/charger-ics/overview.html

Comment: Search for "PMIC", you'll find plenty. Also nearly all dev boards which support use of a battery allow charging it as well, you can look up what IC they use for that. And of course there's the infamous TP4056.

Comment: Consider also buying a ready-made power bank: it does what you need, it's reliable, it meets regulations, it's safe, it has a warranty, it's less likely to catch on fire, and it will cost less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are battery charger ICs that can handle the case of a load and battery connected.

This is not a specific recommendation for this chip, but one example is the [BQ21080](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq21080.pdf?).  As you can see in the diagram the charger includes a **Power Path Controller** that automatically allows power to flow from IN to SYS (power source powers load), IN to BAT (power source charges battery), or BAT to SYS (battery powers load).  This is the type of configuration that you would want for a permanently connected battery.

[image]